# What are the "adopted tasks" mentioned in Airflow 2.4 documentation for "stalled_task_timeout"?

Tags: airflow

From the [Airflow 2.4.3 configuration page about the "stalled_task_timeout"](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.4.3/configurations-ref.html#stalled-task-timeout):

> New in version 2.3.1.
>
> Time in seconds after which tasks queued in celery are assumed to be
> stalled, and are automatically  rescheduled. Adopted tasks will
> instead use the task_adoption_timeout setting if specified. When set
> to 0, automatic clearing of stalled tasks is disabled.

Could someone clarify what do they mean by "adopted tasks"?

Also, while we are here - what is the difference between the `stalled_task_timeout` and `task_adoption_timeout` configuration parameters?